# Performance comparison about template parameters of container?

Tags: c++, templates, derived-class

I am developing an application that holds a vector of different types, like below

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <variant>
#include <any>

class Symbol{};
class Terminal : public Symbol{
    Token token;
};
class NonTerminal : public Symbol{};

Terminal main(){
    std::vector< std::any > vec1 = {Terminal(), NonTerminal()};                           // 1
    std::vector< std::variant<Terminal,NonTerminal> > vec2 = {Terminal(), NonTerminal()}; // 2
    std::vector<Symbol> vec3 = {Terminal(), NonTerminal()};                               // 3
}
```

where, `Terminal` and `NonTerminal` are derived classes of `Symbol`, from the basic theory of context-free language. **Among the three vectors, Which is the fastest one, consider iterating the elements?**

A critical problem is that the derived class `Terminal` holds an additional member variable `token`. An alternative implementation (my collegue's idea) would be something like below,

```cpp
#include <vector>

class Symbol{
    bool isTerminal; // to differentiate Terminal and NonTerminal
    Token token;
};

Terminal main(){
    std::vector<Symbol> vec;
}
```

How about this?

Comment: Iterating over elements in a vector is irrelevant of the types of objects stored in the vector.

Comment: By the way, `vec3` will have object slicing problems.

Comment: And it all seems like premature optimization concerns to me. Start with the most clearest, simplest, most readable and most maintainable code you can write. Then *if* (and only if) there are requirements about "effectiveness" or absolute times and it's not "good enough"™ (which often *is* good enough), then you *measure* and *profile* to find the top one or two bottlenecks in the code, and concentrate on only those one or two places, remembering to document any kind of optimization you do since it tends to make code harder to understand and maintain.

Comment: `vec3` should probably be `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Symbol>>`.

Comment: Old code tends to use polymorphism to be able to place them in container. If base class has no behavior or derived classes are not interchangeable, `std::variant` seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

They do different things, so it is meaningless to say which is faster.

`vec1` discards the type information, so you have to remember that you put in `Terminal` then `NonTerminal` elsewhere.

`vec2` retains all the information, so you can `std::visit` each element.

`vec3` doesn't contain any `Terminal` or `NonTerminal` objects, it copied the `Symbol` base subobjects out of the values in the initialiser. Notably the `token` member of `Terminal` is not copied.